# Auto-populate input form-field based on 2 selections from select boxes using CF8 or JS

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I'm relatively new to development, and have been working primarily with MSSQL '05 as my DBMS, ColdFusion 8 for processing and markup.  I have a need to fill in a (simple text/input-type) field dynamically when a user sets a certain choice from a drop-down (select) menu.  This value comes from a single record in the DB.  I found and successfully adapted this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/zunrk/

However this only works for a 1d array...in the context of my application, I need either a 2d array or a sizable block of `cfif` or `cfswitch` code, which would break one of the cardinal rules, D.R.Y.  Also, the `cfif` code would not allow for the dynamic change of the field (not that I know of, anyway)

I would prefer a JS solution since a) I am using it already for this bit and b) would like to learn more JS.  I'm also open to pointers on how I might rearrange this code (especially setting the array elements) to make it more compact and readable.  I am really not very comfortable w/ JS yet but feel fairly competent in CF.

I believe I've included all relevant parts of my code, but if you wish to see more please let me know in a reply and I will get the rest posted.  Thank you in advance, SOers!

PS: I suppose I should explain the business logic as well for clarity's sake.  The DB was built before I started here and was not designed with indexing the 'location' and 'type' variables in mind.  The idea is that, for example, a user is conducting a test of the type 'hair' ([3]) at the locale 'West' ([2]) and wishes to have the 'amt' form-field filled in as soon as they enter those two criteria.  So the code should set 'amt' to LOC[2][3] or, directly, `#rsf.phr#` .

CODE:

```
<query name="rsf" datasource="test">  
  SELECT * FROM fees WHERE company = '#trim(rsc.clientname)#'  
</cfquery>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  var LOC = new Array(6);
  for (var i=0; i < 6; i++){
    LOC[i] = new Array(8);
  }

<cfoutput>
  LOC[0][0] = "";
  LOC[0][1] = "#rsf.pua#";
  LOC[0][2] = "#rsf.pba#";
  LOC[0][3] = "#rsf.phr#";
  LOC[0][4] = "#rsf.pbld#"; 
  LOC[0][5] = "#rsf.pdna#"; 
  LOC[0][6] = "#rsf.ppt#"; 
  LOC[0][7] = "#rsf.pphy#";
  LOC[1][0] = "";
  LOC[1][1] = "#rsf.pua#";
  LOC[1][2] = "#rsf.pba#";
  LOC[1][3] = "#rsf.phr#";
  LOC[1][4] = "#rsf.pbld#"; 
  LOC[1][5] = "#rsf.pdna#"; 
  LOC[1][6] = "#rsf.ppt#"; 
  LOC[1][7] = "#rsf.pphy#";
  LOC[2][0] = "";
  LOC[2][1] = "#rsf.pua#";
  LOC[2][2] = "#rsf.pba#";
  LOC[2][3] = "#rsf.phr#";
  LOC[2][4] = "#rsf.pbld#"; 
  LOC[2][5] = "#rsf.pdna#"; 
  LOC[2][6] = "#rsf.ppt#"; 
  LOC[2][7] = "#rsf.pphy#";
  LOC[3][0] = "";
  LOC[3][1] = "#rsf.pua#";
  LOC[3][2] = "#rsf.pba#";
  LOC[3][3] = "#rsf.phr#";
  LOC[3][4] = "#rsf.pbld#"; 
  LOC[3][5] = "#rsf.pdna#"; 
  LOC[3][6] = "#rsf.ppt#"; 
  LOC[3][7] = "#rsf.pphy#";
  LOC[4][0] = "";
  LOC[4][1] = "#rsf.mpua#";
  LOC[4][2] = "#rsf.mpba#";
  LOC[4][3] = "#rsf.mphr#";
  LOC[4][4] = "#rsf.mpbld#"; 
  LOC[4][5] = "#rsf.mpdna#"; 
  LOC[4][6] = "#rsf.mppt#"; 
  LOC[4][7] = "#rsf.mpphy#";
  LOC[5][0] = "";
  LOC[5][1] = "#rsf.cpua#";
  LOC[5][2] = "#rsf.cpba#";
  LOC[5][3] = "#rsf.cphr#";
  LOC[5][4] = "#rsf.cpbld#"; 
  LOC[5][5] = "#rsf.cpdna#"; 
  LOC[5][6] = "#rsf.cppt#"; 
  LOC[5][7] = "#rsf.cpphy#";
</cfoutput>  

  function LOC(){
    x = document.getElementById("location");
  }

  function CHOICE(){
    y = document.getElementById("type");
      document.getElementById("LOC").value = LOC[x.selectedIndex][y.selectedIndex];
  }

</script>



  <tr>
    <td><br><b>Encounter Information:</b></td>    
  </tr>
<cfoutput>  
  <tr><td style="vertical-align:top">

    CoC:<input type="text" name="coc" size="10" maxlength="20" value="">
    Auth. No.:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="auth" size="10" maxlenght="20" value="">
    Reason:<select name="reason" id="reason">
        <option value="Pre-Emp">Pre-Employment</option>
        <option value="Random">Random</option>
        <option value="Post Acc.">Post-Accident</option>
        <option value="RTD">RTD(Return-to-Duty)</option>
        <option value="Reason. Sus">Reasonable Suspicion</option>
        <option value="Personal">Personal</option> </select>
    Type:<select name="type" id="type" onChange="CHOICE();">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">UA</option>
        <option value="2">BA</option>
        <option value="3">Hair</option>
        <option value="4">Blood</option>
        <option value="5">DNA</option>
        <option value="6">Paternity</option>
        <option value="7">Physical</option></select><br>
    Amt:$<input type="text" id="TP" name="amt">
    <form>
      <input type="checkbox" name="obs" value="Y"><em>Observed</em>
      <input type="checkbox" name="dot" value="Y"><em>DOT</em>    
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
    Location:<select name="location" id="location" onChange="LOC();">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">Amidon</option>
        <option value="2">West</option>
        <option value="3">Tyler</option>
        <option value="4">Mobile</option>
        <option value="5">Callout</option></select>
```

Comment: So what's not working?

Comment: Why is your CFQUERY tag not being looped in the CFOUTPUT? I don't get how this could work? Also, what's your exact problem? If you don't have an exact bug / issue, then you might consider posting this on the 'code review' website here at Stack Exchange.

Comment: Busches, no amount (despite the fact that dumping the query shows there IS an amount) populates the field 'amt' when an end-user selects a 'location' and 'type' from the respective dropdown/select boxes. @Michael: I'm not sure how to go about that as the first 3 indices for LOC (in the JS block) are the same values.  Only the latter two have a different value.  If there were a way to say, add an M or C after '#rsf.' and before 'pua#' etc. then that would be much more efficient but I'm not sure how to do that.  Also the tips and pointers are just an aside, the main problem is aforementioned.

Answer (score 2):

ColdFusion has already written all the javascript you need to do this.  To access it, you use the keyword "bind" in your cfinput tag.  The [documentation for cfinput](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=ajaxdata_03.html) will get you started.  They even have examples.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I'll check that out and reply here if I have any trouble...didn't know about that option as I'm still finding my 'sealegs' w/ CF